# My app crashes when I clicked the button which will take me the another Activity on Java, Android Studio

Tags: java, android

firstly sorry for my bad english, I hope you can understand me.
I'm making an android app on Android Studio. And I'm here because my app crashes while I start the Third Activity.

Well, I have three activies. Going to second from the first and going to first from second works well, But when I tried to go to Third from Second, I press the Button to go to Third Activity, and my app crashes, it says "Unfortunately, Project Saya has stopped."

Here's my `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.missmagius.projectsaya.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Merhaba, Project Saya'ya hoşgeldiniz! Başlamadan önce sorun yaşamamak için lütfen talimatları gözden geçirin. İyi eğlenceler!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Talimatlar"
        android:id="@+id/buttonActOne"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's `MainActivity.java`

```
    package com.missmagius.projectsaya;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnOne =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActOne);
        btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityTwo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Here's `activity_two.xml`

```
package com.missmagius.projectsaya;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnOne =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActOne);
        btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityTwo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Here's `ActivityTwo.java`

```
package com.missmagius.projectsaya;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ActivityTwo extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnTwo;
    Button getBtnTwo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

        Button btnTwo =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActTwo);
        Button btnThree=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActThree);

        btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
        });

        btnThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent4 = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this,SpeechActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent4);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Here's `activity_speech.xml`(Third Activity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.missmagius.projectsaya.SpeechActivity">

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/txtKGiris"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    />

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ImageButton

        android:id="@+id/btnKonus"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@null"
        android:src="@+id/micc" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tap_on_mic"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's `SpeechActivity.java`

```
package com.missmagius.projectsaya;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Locale;




public class SpeechActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtKGiris;
    private ImageButton btnKonus;
    private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speech);

        txtKGiris = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtKGiris);
        btnKonus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnKonus);

        // action bar’ı gizle
        getActionBar().hide();

        btnKonus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                promptSpeechInput();

            }

        });
    }
    /**

     * Google konuşma girişi diyalogunu gösterme

     * */

    private void promptSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent3.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent3.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent3.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                getString(R.string.speech_prompt));

        try {

            startActivityForResult(intent3, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

                    getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),

                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

    /**

     * Konuşma girişi kabulü.

     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    txtKGiris.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present. getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here's `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.missmagius.projectsaya">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityTwo" />
        <activity android:name=".SpeechActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's `Strings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Project Saya</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Ayarlar</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Merhaba Dünya!</string>
    <string name="speech_prompt">Bana bir şeyler söyle.</string>
    <string name="speech_not_supported">Çok Üzgünüm! Senin sürümün buna yetmiyor…</string>
    <string name="tap_on_mic">Mikrofona basıp konuşabilirsin.</string>
</resources>
```

My Error Log:

```
04-27 09:55:26.880 6606-6606/com.missmagius.projectsaya E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.missmagius.projectsaya, PID: 6606
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.missmagius.projectsaya/com.missmagius.projectsaya.SpeechActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class ImageButton
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class ImageButton
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
                                                                              at com.missmagius.projectsaya.SpeechActivity.onCreate(SpeechActivity.java:27)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
                                                                           Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.missmagius.projectsaya:id/micc" (7f0c0054)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0054}
                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2390)
                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
                                                                              at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                                                                              at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
                                                                              at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:86)
                                                                              at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:82)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:57)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:53)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:114)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1030)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
                                                                              at com.missmagius.projectsaya.SpeechActivity.onCreate(SpeechActivity.java:27) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

That's it. I don't know where did I make mistake. I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Everyone scrolls top to bottom searching for Crash Log. Post that. And don't dump your whole codes, Only post relevant parts of it. You have to see the crash log, `Unfortunately stopped working` is seen by end user.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Sorry, I don't have any crash log, I can run my app in the phone well but when I clicked the button it crashes.

Comment: Didn't it show any messages in android studio as error ?

Comment: The fact you don't have a crash log and this much code is extremely telling. You are asking too early in the process. You need to make some effort to narrow down the problem, get an error message, and post that along with the relevant parts of code.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I added the error log.

Comment: @tnw I added the error log..

Comment: @LaraCroft Are you sure your all images are in drawable folder. Not in like `drawable-v21` and others.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna yes, I have one image and it's in drawable folder. I'm sure about it.

Comment: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.missmagius.projectsaya:id/micc" (7f0c0054)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0054}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `android:src="@+id/micc"` to `android:src="@drawable/micc" />` in `ImageButton`. It's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code

**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**

To :

**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Application contexts are not allowed to start Activities unless the Intent contains the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.

Simply change (at least)

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

To :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Inside the clickListener in your `MainActivity`

Comment: I'm gonna try your answer when I fixed my new error :S

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working :/  I added the error log btw

Answer (score 0):

You missed to finish your old activity just add `finish()` after `startActivity()`

so this is the code:

```
startActivity(i);
finish();
```